# Lubuntu 16.04 LTS frequently crashes

Tags: lubuntu, dell, laptop, crash

I recently installed Lubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 1525 given to me by a relative. For the most part it works well and is quite fast even on the older hardware. However, I am experiencing crashes fairly often and I am not sure why. The display turns black, the CPU seems to experience high usage, then I am presented with this [black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUgCy.jpg) [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP4nI.jpg) with white text.

Below the summary section of a report generated by the System Profiler and Benchmark tool.

> > ---Summary---
>
> Processor     : 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5750  @ 2.00GHz
>
> Memory        : 3089MB (1374MB used) Operating System     : Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
>
> User Name     : j******** (j*******)
>
> Date/Time     : Tue 25 Apr 2017 10:20:20 AM EDT
>
> -Display-
>
> Resolution        : 1280x800 pixels
>
> OpenGL Renderer       : Unknown
>
> X11 Vendor        : The X.Org Foundation
>
> -Multimedia-
>
> Audio Adapter     : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
>
> -Input Devices-
>
> - Lid Switch
> - Power Button
> - Sleep Button
> - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
> - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
> - Video Bus
> - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
> - AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint
> - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
> - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
> - Dell WMI hotkeys
> - HDA Intel HDMI/DP,pcm       : 3=
> - HDA Intel Front Headphone Front
> - HDA Intel Front Headphone Surround
>
> -Printers (CUPS)- billing_office_HPdeskjetpro     : *Default*
>
> -SCSI Disks-
>
> - TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-L632H
> - ATA TOSHIBA MK2552GS

I've been using this PC daily at my job and the crashes are interrupting my work. I am still fairly new to GNU+Linux so any advice or help would be greatly appreciated! I would be happy to provide any other details as needed. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like I should have mentioned that the crashes seem to occur when the system attempts to return from being suspended or when the display powers off due to energy save settings. Thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same thing so I decided to turn off the suspend mode and the power off. It wont solve the problem, but it will bypass it and thus will be at least functional and less prone to data loss.